# how to get the loginstatus using fbml and how to maintain the facebook session in my application?

Tags: fbml

Hi All below is the code which i use.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>ABI SocialWebConnect</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            body {
                font-family : arial, sans-serif;
            }
            #spacer { width : 10px; }
            #friendWrapperCanvas {
                border : 2px solid #979797;
                width : 85%;
                height : 100px;
            }
            #mapWrapperCanvas {
                border : 2px solid #979797;
                width : 85%;
                height : 380px;
                padding-top: 10%;
            }
            #mapCanvas {
                border : 2px solid #979797;
                height : 380px;
                width : 100%;
            }
            #resultsCanvas {
                position : relative;
                top : 15px;
                left : 0px;
                height : 370px;
                width : 280px;
            }
            #mapSearch {
                position: relative;
                top : 0px;
                left : 0px;
            }
            .mapcanvastable td {
                padding : 0px;
            }
            .mapcanvastable {
                border-width : 0px;
                border-spacing : 0px;
                border-collapse : collapse;
                border : none;
                padding-top: 10%;
            }

            /* canvas view css over-rides */
            #mapCanvas .gels {
                width : 280px;
                background-color: #ddeeff;
            }
            #mapCanvas .gels-form {
                background-color: #ddeeff;
            }

            #mapWrapperCanvas .gels-controls {
                position : absolute;
                bottom : -2px;
                left : 0px;
            }
            #mapWrapperCanvas .gels-app,
            #mapWrapperCanvas .gels-extresults-active {
                border : none;
            }
            #mapWrapperCanvas .gels-list-item {
                margin-bottom : 2px;
            }
            #mapWrapperCanvas .gels-list-wrapper {
                padding-left : 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
        <div id="friendWrapperCanvas">
            <h3>Connect with Facebook</h3>
            <form name="comment_form" method="post">
                <div id="user">
                    <fb:login-button length='long' onlogin="update_user_box();" autologoutlink='true'>Logout</fb:login-button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function update_user_box() {
                var user_box = document.getElementById("user");
                user_box.innerHTML =
                    "<span>" +
                    "<table><tr>" +
                    "<td>" +
                    "<fb:profile-pic uid='loggedinuser' facebook-logo='true'></fb:profile-pic>" +
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td><fb:login-button length='long' autologoutlink='true'>Logout</fb:login-button></td>"+
                    "<td >" +
                    "<fb:name uid='loggedinuser' useyou='false'></fb:name>" +
                    "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"submitComment();\" value=\"Post to Your Wall\"> ." +
                    "</td></tr><tr>" +
                    "<td colspan='3'>" +
                    "<fb:comments xid='user_comments' canpost='true' showform='true'>"+
                    "</fb:comments>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "</tr></table></span>";

                FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree();
            }

            function submitComment() {

                FB.Connect.streamPublish(null, null, null, null, "Share your Search...", null, false, null);
            }

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" mce_src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var api_key = "389895527688846";
            var channel_path = "xd_receiver.htm";
           FB.init(api_key, channel_path);
        </script>
    </body>
    <script>
       validateUserStatus();
        var uid;
        var accessToken;
        function validateUserStatus(){
            alert('called before getting login status');
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                var user = document.getElementById("user");
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                     alert('called before getting login status : connected');
                    user.innerHTML =
                        "<span>" +
                        "<table> <tr>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        "<fb:profile-pic uid='loggedinuser' facebook-logo='true'></fb:profile-pic>" +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td >" +
                        "<fb:name uid='loggedinuser' useyou='false'></fb:name>" +
                        " <input type=\"button\" onclick=\"submitComment();\" value=\"Post to Your Wall\"> ." +
                        "</td></tr><tr>" +
                        "<td colspan='2'>" +
                        "<fb:comments xid='user_comments' canpost='true' showform='true'>"+
                        " </fb:comments>"
                        + "</td>"
                    "</tr></table>" +
                        + "</span>";
                    uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                       alert('called before getting login status : not-connected');
                    user.innerHTML =
                        "<span>" +
                        "<table> <tr>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        "<fb:login-button length='long' onlogin='update_user_box();' autologoutlink='true'>Logout></fb:login-button>" +
                        "</td></tr></table>"+"</span>";
                } else {
                    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                }
                FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree();
            });
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

i have two questions here.

1. FB.loginStatus is not giving me me the status
2. i get the user profile image with the name when i click on the user's image it goes to facebook but i don't want that go to facebook because i integrated this in my own  application. so it should remain in the same window or application.

Please advise me how to go about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question, to prevent the user's image from linking out to Facebook, you can use jQuery to remove the href attribute of the anchor tag that is generated.

```
$(".fb_profile_pic_rendered .fb_link").removeAttr("href");
```